# Npgsql error 42601

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

I have written a function in postgresql with one inpute parameter. I want to invoke this function from .Net windows Form but an error occures like this:
**Error: 42601: Syntaxerror at »'TestUGI'«**
this is my code:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=DB3;User Id=postgres;Password=123456;");
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("'TestUGI'",conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", "'csnnutzer'");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show the function. That would help a lot. If, for instance the function returns a record, then should you make a different kind of call.

Error 42883 states that the function is undefined. That has a straightforward reason. If you show the code, we can help you to find out. The parameter unknown is not the problem. When I read that, I know that there is text or varchar without a specified length.

Is the capitalization correct? The functions 'testUGI' and 'TestUgi' are different.

When the function does not return a record, then should you just make a query. It is not like a stored procedure in MySQL, which has a syntax on its own (call etc.). In postgresql is the call to a function a select statement.

Some examples:

```
select func();
select * from func();
select * from func() as (id int, name varchar);
```

The first function can return a simple datatype like integer or varchar.
The second statement when there is a row of table returned.
The last one when you return a record.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a function use

```
select TestUGI('csnnutzer');
```

You can't "just call" a function in PostgreSQL.

Comment: but i want to use it in .net

Comment: @Kabi: I'm sure .net can run a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: but where should I write it?

Comment: @Kabi: it's a plain SQL `SELECT` statement. You put it whereever you put SQL statements in .Net

Answer (score 0):

Take the single quotes out:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("TestUGI",conn);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", "csnnutzer");
```

In ADO.Net you must pass the parameter type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16);
```

Try to find how to do it in `NpgSQL`

Comment: @Kabi What is the error? There is another pair of single quotes in `"'csnnutzer'"`. Take that out also.

Comment: Error: 42883: Function testugi(unknown) doesnt exist.

Comment: @Kabi So your original problem is solved. Now you have another one. It is the type of the parameter that is missing. Check the update answer.

Comment: What is the signature of your function? are you able to call your function like that?: select * from TestUGI('csnnutzer');